# Unable to locate xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Here is my HTML code:

[image]

I want to go to the tr where the label is CompanyId and get the td text which is 512571(last line). How can I achive this?

Here is what I tried:

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[contains(text(), "CompanyId")]').text

Comment: I do not want to use Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following xpath should work:

```
//th[label[contains(text(),'CompanyId')]]/following-sibling::td
```

Relevant line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[label[contains(text(),'CompanyId')]]/following-sibling::td").text
```

**Note:** by default the xpath will select the first occurrence of a td - in this case CompanyId looks like a label that is immediately followed by the data you are looking for. You could always use an index of you always want the first td

```
//th[label[contains(text(),'CompanyId')]]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go to parent `tr` of that label and then direct child node of type `td`.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[contains(text(), "CompanyId")]//parent::tr/td').text
```

That is assuming there is only one `td` in that `tr`.

Comment: It is giving - raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//label[contains(text(), "CompanyId")]/parent::tr/td"}

Comment: also there is only one td

Comment: try with double slashes before parent. updated answer.